# Issue while executing cmd from java code

Tags: java, service, cmd

I have a requirement where i want to see the status of all the running services on a remote server by
executing the some java program.

For this I tried using the Service controller functionality of cmd.

When i execute the following command from command prompt it works fine-

**sc \RemoteServerName queryex type= service state= all**

But when i tried executing the same command from a java program it doesn't work. Following is the
java code

```
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
            "cmd.exe", "/c", "sc \\RemoteServerName queryex type= service state= all");
    builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process p = builder.start();
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while (true) {
        line = r.readLine();
        if (line == null) { break; }
        System.out.println(line);
    }
```

It returns something like this- 
ERROR:  Unrecognized command

DESCRIPTION:
        SC is a command line program used for communicating with the
        Service Control Manager and services.

Is there is any special parameters we need to pass for running command on remote server?
Any idea on this guys?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the second `\` on the server name.

Running your command as you have it pasted shows the same error you're seeing in the command window.

From the `sc` help:

> DESCRIPTION:
>          SC is a command line program used for communicating with the
>          Service Control Manager and services.
>
> USAGE:
>          sc  [command] [service name]  ...
>
> ```
>    The option <server> has the form "\\ServerName"
>    Further help on commands can be obtained by typing: "sc [command]"
> ```

Your command shows the slash is missing `sc \RemoteServerName queryex type= service state= all`

Change it to this:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
        "cmd.exe", "/c", "sc \\\\RemoteServerName queryex type= service state= all");
```

and it should work properly.

My output (which won't return proper results for obvious reasons) shows the `sc` command is working properly.

```
[SC] OpenSCManager FAILED 1722:

The RPC server is unavailable.
```